# What's the time complexity of this alg $ for(i = 0; i \le (logn)^{\frac{\sqrt n}{2}}; i = i \cdot 3)$

Tags: functions, algorithms

**Given algorithm:**

1. $x \leftarrow 0$
2. $ for(i = 0; i \le (logn)^{\frac{\sqrt n}{2}}; i = i \cdot 3)$
3. $x \leftarrow x + 2$

Well, lines 1,3 are useless.

about line 2. I'm not sure how to build the equation but I think it is:

$3^i \le (logn)^{\frac{\sqrt n}{2}}$, can anyone help explain how to build the in-equality to find $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to write $i = 1$ rather than $i = 0$, you're almost there.  Just take the logarithm of both sides, and you'll get $$i \le \frac{\sqrt n\log\log n}{2\log 3}$$  So the number of iterations of the loop will be proportional to the square root of n, which may be sublinear or exponential in terms of input size, depending on whether n is the input itself or the size of the input.

Of course, if you do start with $i = 0$, you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for approving what I did, How did you get $log3$ in the denominator? somehow from $log_3$ to $\frac{log}{log3}$

Comment: Btw, the $\Theta$ would be the right side of your in-equality right?

Comment: I've clarified above - it depends on whether n is your input or the size of your input.  The right side of the inequality is the number of loops.  The log I took was in whatever base the log in the for loop was, which gives i*log 3; the equation you ask about is a precalc identity.

Comment: I see. so I've concluded this to $\Theta (\frac{\sqrt{n} log_3logn} {2})$

Comment: @Ilan: FYI, note that $\Theta( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n} \log_3 \log n ) = \Theta( \sqrt{n} \log \log n)$....

Comment: @Hurkyl Oh right, I'm stupid lol